# adding item in to react state at certain position related to the item at hand?

Tags: javascript

How to update state array to add a value after related position rather than at the end of the array ? in the example below for example I want rice to go after rice rather than after bananas ? , this current logic is making thing really mixed when I want to render items according to what the user has selected to be the first item.

```js
let stateArr = [{item : cucumber}, {item : rice }, {item: bannan }, {item : rice }]

// current state logic 

[...stateArr, newItem ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep things immutable, you can [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) your array at the point you want to insert the new item, and spread those two slices around your new value.

```js
let stateArr = [
    { item: "cucumber" },
    { item: "rice" },
    { item: "bannan" },
    { item: "fish" },
];

// First, find the location of the item you want to insert _after_
const riceIndex = stateArr.findIndex(({ item }) => item === "rice");

const newItem = { item: "crab" };

// Next, slice _right after_ that item (+ 1)
const newState = [
    ...stateArr.slice(0, riceIndex + 1),
    newItem,
    ...stateArr.slice(riceIndex + 1),
];

console.log(newState);
```

Comment: the problem in my code it is sorting the array alphabetically for some reason